# Have a button table instead of a lot of variables

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, gpiozero

Novice in pyhton AND Raspberry prog, i want to create a Quizz-buzz Game. Up to 8 players can play it.

To catch the event when a button is pressed, (using the `gpiozero` lib) i want to do something like :

```
buttons = [Button(4), Button(5), Button(6), ....]
buttons.when_pressed = lambda : buttonpressed(buttons.buttonPressedIndex)
```

Rather than

```
button1 = Button(1)
button2 = Button(2)
button3 = Button(3)
....

button1.when_pressed = lambda : buttonpressed(1)
button2.when_pressed = lambda : buttonpressed(2)
....
```

Is it possible to do something like this ?
How can i know which index of my array are trigger ?

Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

1. You can move the `when_pressed` initialization to Button's
   constructor.
2. You can declare a list of buttons: `buttons = [Button(i) for i in range(N)]`
   and then set their `when_pressed` function like that:   `for button in buttons: button.when_pressed = lambda: buttonpressed(button.buttonPressedIndex)`